# Haskell- IO String get multiple Lines

Tags: string, list, haskell, io

I am trying to write a function that gets multiple string inputs and terminates on an empty line ('\n') I have following

```
getLines :: IO [String]
getLines = do x <- getLine
           if x == ""
           return ()
           else do xs <- getLines
                return (x:xs)
```

it fails to compile saying there is something wrong with the if statement

Ideally I want to to work like this

getLines

Apple

Bird

Cat

(enter is pressed)

Output:
["Apple","Bird","Cat"]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `then` after `if`, and `()` (empty tuple) should be `[]` (empty list). In `if`, the `then` and `else` need to be indented as well if they’re on separate lines, because `if then else` is an operator, and the compiler needs to know that the expression continues. Your indentation needs to be adjusted so that everything is indented more than the leading `do`:

```
getLines :: IO [String]
getLines = do x <- getLine
              if x == ""
                then return []
                else do xs <- getLines
                        return (x:xs)
```

Or everything is indented more than the *line* containing the leading `do`:

```
getLines :: IO [String]
getLines = do
  x <- getLine
  if x == ""
    then return []
    else do
      xs <- getLines
      return (x:xs)
```

As a matter of style, you can also use `null x` instead of `x == ""`.

Comment: `(x:) <$> getLines` is also possible. Not better by definition, but I prefer it over `do`-notation in this case. Needs `import Control.Applicative ((<$>))`, though.

Comment: @Zoidberg: Yes, I generally prefer applicative style, but didn’t want to change the example unduly. It can also be written `getLines = untilNull getLine`, where `untilNull` is defined pointfree and spacefree as `execWriterT.fix.ap(liftM(=<<)(ap(unless.null).ap(liftM(>>)(tell.(:[]))).const)).const.lift` with the appropriate imports.

Answer (score 1):

This is nearly right.

You need a `then` after your `if`. You may also need to change the indentation slightly, so that everything is indented as far as the `x` rather than the `do`. I think that should just about do it.

Comment: It also won't typecheck at the moment, I think `return ()` should be `return []`. `[]` is an empty list, `()` is unit.